# Chawmaysh mayoys, chawmeeshuh ussawr (515) mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

B"H

What's significant about 515 in the Torah?

Blessings and success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Midrash Tanchumah](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Terumah.9.5?ven=Midrash_Tanhuma-Yelammedenu,_trans._Samuel_A._Berman&lang=bi) on Parshas Terumah 9:5 notes that whilst there is a difference of 500 years from the earth to the rekiah (firmament) there is 515 years that separates the earth and the טַּלְפֵי הַחַיּוֹת - steps of the beasts that pull the maaseh merkavah (Divine chariot).

Answer (score 1):

B"H

It is the number of tefillos Moyshe made in order to enter the land of Yisroyayl, same gematria as "vieschawnawn" (and he prayed, second parsha of devarim)

The source is in the midrash

https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1590696/jewish/Entreaties-and-Prayers.htm

Blessings and success